# Sum TimeSpan array with a one-liner?

Tags: .net, extension-methods, aggregate, timespan, accumulate

Is there a way to aggregate multiple aggregates to 1 time span?

```
Dim times = { 
  New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0),
  New TimeSpan(1, 10, 0),
  New TimeSpan(1, 50, 0),
  New TimeSpan(0, 20, 0),
  New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
}

Dim sum As New TimeSpan
For Each ts In times
  sum = sum.Add(ts)
Next

'That's what I desire:
sum = times.Sum
sum = times.Aggregate
```

I am looking for some built in capability I don't know about.

**Update**
Please read my comment on [Reed Copsey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239319/sum-timespan-array/3239359#3239359).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C#:

```
TimeSpan sum = times.Aggregate((t1, t2) => t1.Add(t2));
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim sum As TimeSpan = times.Aggregate(Function(t1, t2) t1.Add(t2))
```

Comment: @Shimmy: Thank you, was in the process of looking it up.

Comment: Yeah, np... lolz, I accepted since it's the exact one liner I was looking for no bs

Answer (score 2):

You have the answer there - just use [TimeSpan.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx).

You can do the collection using LINQ's [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) if you want to avoid the loop:

```
Dim sum as TimeSpan
sum = times.Aggregate(Function(ByVal current, ByVal ts) ts.Add(current) )
```

---

Edit: If you want an extension method to do this, you could do:

```
''
<Extension()> 
Public Function Aggregate(ByVal IEnumerable(Of TimeSpan) times) As TimeSpan
     Return times.Aggregate(Function(ByVal current, ByVal ts) ts.Add(current) )
End Function
```

Comment: I think my question is more about the extension-methods, the time-span is just the victim. I wanna learn if there is a way to do somethig like this with extension methods.

Comment: @Shimmy: Yeah - I just edited to show you how to do it with LINQ.  However, your question is VERY poorly worded.  Add does aggregate the values...

Comment: You're right. but I stated in my examples what I want, anyway, you do deserve the upvote I committed indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

[`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) just needs a `Func<T, T, T>` -- something that takes two `T` objects and aggregates them in some way to product a new `T`. So you can go with [Yuriy's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239319/sum-timespan-array/3239374#3239374):

```
// The + operator is defined for TimeSpan, so you're fine just using that.
TimeSpan sum = times.Aggregate((t1, t2) => t1 + t2);
```

Or, you can also do something *like* [what Tim Coker suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239319/sum-timespan-array/3239370#3239370), using the [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534643.aspx) extension method:

```
TimeSpan sum = TimeSpan.FromTicks(times.Sum(t => t.Ticks));
```

**Update**: Here are the VB.NET equivalents:

```
Dim sum = times.Aggregate(Function(t1, t2) t1 + t2)

Dim sum = TimeSpan.FromTicks(times.Sum(Function(t) t.Ticks))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Sum` method to add the `Ticks` value from each `TimeSpan`:

```
Dim times = { _
  New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0), _
  New TimeSpan(1, 10, 0), _
  New TimeSpan(1, 50, 0), _
  New TimeSpan(0, 20, 0), _
  New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0) _
}

Dim t As New TimeSpan(times.Sum(Function(t) t.Ticks))
```

Comment: @Shimmy: Line continuation put back, as it doesn't compile without it.

Comment: And that's the reason I am so attached to VB 10, with all its new features it's for my taste the best language in the world!

Comment: @Shimmy: Line continuation put back again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum `TimeSpan.Ticks` then create a new `TimeSpan` with that value

```
Dim times = 
{ 
    New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0), 
    New TimeSpan(1, 10, 0), 
    New TimeSpan(1, 50, 0), 
    New TimeSpan(0, 20, 0), 
    New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0) 
}

Dim sumTicks As Long = 0
For Each ts In times
    sumTicks += ts.Ticks
Next

Dim sum As New TimeSpan(sumTicks)
```